# xamarin Android application crashing randomly in native code

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I get the stack trace below when I try to log the exception causing the crash:

```
System.Exception: CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.RuntimeException' was thrown.
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001f] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Android.Views.ViewGroup.Layout (System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00062] in <16f010a2e2ef4e92ac94d31ae1a1fe76>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer`2[TView,TNativeView].OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00059] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.53(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.MeasureAndLayout (System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00090] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateLayout () [0x00163] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout () [0x0001c] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] children) [0x00038] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0001e] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 left, System.Int32 top, System.Int32 right, System.Int32 bottom) [0x00000] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.53(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.MeasureAndLayout (System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00090] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateLayout () [0x00163] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout () [0x0001c] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] children) [0x00038] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0001e] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 left, System.Int32 top, System.Int32 right, System.Int32 bottom) [0x00000] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.53(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.MeasureAndLayout (System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00090] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateLayout () [0x00163] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout () [0x0001c] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] children) [0x00038] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0001e] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 left, System.Int32 top, System.Int32 right, System.Int32 bottom) [0x00000] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.53(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.MeasureAndLayout (System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00090] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateLayout () [0x00163] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout () [0x0001c] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] children) [0x00038] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0001e] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 left, System.Int32 top, System.Int32 right, System.Int32 bottom) [0x00000] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.53(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.MeasureAndLayout (System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00090] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateLayout () [0x00163] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout () [0x0001c] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] children) [0x00038] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0001e] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PageRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00000] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.53(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.MeasureAndLayout (System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00090] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateLayout () [0x00163] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout () [0x0001c] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] children) [0x00038] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0001e] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x000e8] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.53(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup.MeasureAndLayout (System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00090] in <0da584894ce84efd8a9c47c2e3604669>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateLayout () [0x00163] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateLayout () [0x0001c] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FlyoutPageContainer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0004d] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <16f010a2e2ef4e92ac94d31ae1a1fe76>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.47(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00063] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at AndroidX.DrawerLayout.Widget.DrawerLayout.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00079] in <108bc11afc0f4ea9a4d8d7845f34be04>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FlyoutPageRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00000] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at AndroidX.DrawerLayout.Widget.DrawerLayout.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <108bc11afc0f4ea9a4d8d7845f34be04>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.137(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001f] in <edeadab5b81d46918be425e8254d3c42>:0 
  at Android.Views.ViewGroup.Layout (System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00062] in <16f010a2e2ef4e92ac94d31ae1a1fe76>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateLayout () [0x00109] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FlyoutPageRenderer.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.UpdateLayout () [0x0000a] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPlatformLayout.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0002b] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00024] in <41c62ef5294c490cb793ec745b9dc405>:0 
  at Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <16f010a2e2ef4e92ac94d31ae1a1fe76>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.47(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The stack trace does not give me much to go on, but I am hoping that someone has faced something similar and would have some information on how to tackle this.

Xamarin forms version is **5.0.0.2125**; Android target framework version: **Android: 11**

Comment: Can you debug the application or add a try catch to find which line caused the crash?

Comment: 1) Try to find a scenario that produces crash
2) Identify the screen. Then the UI (xaml) code that crashes. According to your trace: it should be somewhere with different Layout (Stacklayout, grid, ...).
Most of the time, this type of crashes are caused by "not optimized" visual tree. In the worst case, a bug in Xamarin Forms where you could find a workaround.